# \sum not coming out right

Tags: math-operators

I am trying to write this:

[image: this]

Using

```
$$p_{\Theta | X} = \frac{p_{\Theta}(\theta) p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta)}{\sum_{\theta ‘} p_{\Theta}(\theta ‘) p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta ‘)}$$
```

However, what I get is this instead:

[image: that]

The theta prime of the summation does not come out right.  Please help.

Comment: note you should not use `$$` in latex, and it is not a case of wrong or right, the subscript position is quote standard layout in compressed contexts like inline math or fractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Must use `\limits` after `\sum`

```
$$p_{\Theta | X} = \frac{p_{\Theta}(\theta) p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta)}{\sum\limits_{\theta '} p_{\Theta}(\theta ') p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta ')}$$
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  How come it still came out right with out `limit` when it is not inside a fraction?

Comment: `$$p_{\Theta | X} = \frac{p_{\Theta}(\theta) p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta)}{\displaystyle\sum_{\theta '} p_{\Theta}(\theta ') p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta ')}$$` Use `\displaystyle` inside the `\frac`

Comment: Thank you for the extra answer.  What I meant is when not used in a fraction like this case, it comes out right without using `limit` like you show in the answer above.  Why the difference?

Comment: The `\frac` command, which is in the basic command set of LATEX, takes two
arguments—numerator and denominator—and typesets them in normal fraction
form. The `amsmath` package provides also `\dfrac` and `\tfrac` as convenient
abbreviations for `{\displaystyle\frac ... }` and `{\textstyle\frac ... }`.

Comment: That's "`\limits`", not "`\limit`".

Comment: Peraphs, for my humble opinion, it is better `\mid` instead of `|`.